# Loading 50GB CSV File Azure Blob to Azure SQL DB in Less time- Performance

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, openrowset

I am loading **50GB CSV file** From **Azure Blob** to **Azure SQL DB** using OPENROWSET.
It takes 7 hours to load this file.
Can you please help me with possible ways to reduce this time?

Comment: That's quite a CSV file.
Storing that amount of data in Azure SQL is going to rack up charges very quickly.
Is this something you need to do on a regular basis or a one time thing?

Comment: I am truncating and loading data into a table on a regular basis with openrowset.

Comment: Like Aleberto said, Azure Data Factory is probably the easiest way. Just keep a very close eye on what you're being charged.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-tool).

First create the destination table on Azure SQL Database, let's call it USDJPY. After that upload the CSV to an Azure Storage Account. Now create your Azure Data Factory instance and choose Copy Data.

[image]

Next, choose "Run once now" to copy your CSV files.

[image]

Choose "Azure Blob Storage" as your "source data store", specify your Azure Storage which you stored CSV files.

[image]

Provide information about Azure Storage account.

[image]

Choose your CSV files from your Azure Storage.

[image]

Choose "Comma" as your CSV files delimiter and input "Skip line count" number if your CSV file has headers

[image]

Choose "Azure SQL Database" as your "destination data store".

[image]

Type your Azure SQL Database information.

[image]

Select your table from your SQL Database instance.

[image]

Verify the data mapping.

[image]

Execute data copy from CSV files to SQL Database just confirming next wizards.

[image]

Comment: Try this not seeing much improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option IMHO is just use BULK INSERT. Move the csv file into a Blob Store and the import it directly using BULK INSERT from Azure SQL. Make sure Azure Blob storage and Azure SQL are in the same Azure region.

To make it as fast as possible:

1. split the CSV in more than one file (for example using something like a CSV splitter. This looks nice https://www.erdconcepts.com/dbtoolbox.html. Never tried and just came up with a simple search, but looks good)
2. run more BULK INSERT in parallel using TABLOCK option. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments). This, if the target table is empty, will allow multiple concurrent bulk operations in parallel.
3. make sure you are using an higher SKU for the duration of the operation. Depending on the SLO (Service Level Objective) you're using (S4? P1, vCore?) you will get a different amount of log throughput, up to close 100 MB/Sec. That's the maximum speed you can actually achieve. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-resource-limits-database-server)